# How to remove comment from sales order in magento1.9.3.6

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to remove Comment from sales order in magento admin panel.This is comment saved after payment successful/declined etc from **Authorize.Net** .i don't want to save this messages into the order comment.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to 
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\history.phtml

and comment line number 57-76

Comment: @parmer Thank you but i have comment box on the checkout page if i will remove from the files then other comment will not showing . i just want to remove comment Authorize.Net payment successful comment from database

Comment: you need to doing code on that extension

Comment: @parmer any idea  ??\

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got the Solution 
**Note:** Don't edit the core files
**app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Helper/data.php copy to app/code/local/Mage/Paygate/Helper/data.php**
and Edit the code function getTransactionMessage on line number 54
and comment this code    
    // return $this->getExtendedTransactionMessage($payment, $requestType, $lastTransactionId, $card, $amount, $exception);

after done this step 

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Observer.php copy to 
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Observer.php**

line no 459 remove this message
              //  $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Captured amount of %s online.', $this->_formatPrice($amountToCapture));

And it's working fine please have a  look on screen shoot

Thank you

[image]